# Expected value of type for association field got "integer" instead

Tags: symfony, doctrine

so i have tow tables with a ManyToONe relationship but whenever i do create operation i get this error

> Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Etat" for association field
>   "AppBundle\Entity\FicheFrais#$id_etat", got "integer" instead.

here you can find my Entites 
https://gist.github.com/Bakhshi-Faisal/bd459aab6ef0e8566c5fceb0789655af

in my controller i set it simple like this

`$ficheFrai->setIdEtat(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entity **FicheFrais** is associated with **Etat** entities.

So you need to set them with an Etat entity and not an id.

So instead of :

```
$ficheFrai->setIdEtat(1);
```

You have to pass an **Etat** object to the setter
Like this :

```
//Do that if you want to set the etat to your Etat with an id of 1
$etat = $em->getRepository(Etat::class)->find(1);
$ficheFrai->setIdEtat($etat);
```

And that should work.

And by the way, since you set your **FicheFrais** with an **Etat** entity
you should rename your attribute, getter and setter :

```
private $etat;

   /**
     * @return Etat
     */
    public function getEtat()
    {
        return $this->etat;
    }

    /**
     * @param Etat $etat
     */
    public function setEtat($etat)
    {
        $this->etat = $etat;
}
```